# GQL Syntax condition

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have a simple question:

In GQL [syntax summary](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html)

```
<condition> := <property> {< | <= | > | >= | = | != } <value>
```

but in an [example here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html)

```
if users.get_current_user():
    user_pets = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE owner = :1",
                            users.get_current_user())
```

What is `:1` ?

According to syntax there should be `:=` there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GQL grammar on the syntax link you posted is this:

```
SELECT [* | __key__] FROM <kind>
  [WHERE <condition> [AND <condition> ...]]
  [ORDER BY <property> [ASC | DESC] [, <property> [ASC | DESC] ...]]
  [LIMIT [<offset>,]<count>]
  [OFFSET <offset>]

<condition> := <property> {< | <= | > | >= | = | != } <value>
<condition> := <property> IN <list>
<condition> := ANCESTOR IS <entity or key>
```

The `:=` in the last three lines means that `<condition>` in the main expression can be replaced with the expression to the right of the `:=` in any of the three `<condition>` statements.

In the example, they have chosen to select `*` instead of `__key__`, the `<kind>` is `Pet`, there is only one `WHERE` condition, and there are no `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` clauses.

So the main expression simplifies to:

```
SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE <condition>
```

We can then substitute the first condition expression, ie:

```
<condition> := <property> {< | <= | > | >= | = | != } <value>
```

Resulting in:

```
SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE <property> {< | <= | > | >= | = | != } <value>
```

In the example, `<property>` is `owner`, the operator is `=`, and the `<value>` is `:1`, ie:

```
SELECT * FROM Pet WHERE owner = :1
```

According to [the documentation for the `GqlQuery` class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html), the :1 means that the value will be bound to the first argument to `GqlQuery()` (after the query). So in the example, the value is `users.get_current_user()`.

**Update:**

I don't think either of those would work, because they are both missing a double quote to end the string of the query. However, both of the following should work:

```
query = db.GqlQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM Rep WHERE author = :1", 
    users.get_current_user())

user = users.get_current_user()
query = db.GqlQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM Rep WHERE author = :1", 
    user)
```

Once you have the query object you can call `fetch()` on it to get the items as a list. Or, you can also iterate directly over the query.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Another quick question: This query works: `query = list(db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Rep WHERE author = users.get_current_user()))` But if I define `user=users.get_current_user()` and try the query `query = list(db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Rep WHERE author=user))` then it does not work. I get the error `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` Any suggestion? Thanks again!